# Breeze.js priming (loading and caching) data via asynchronous requests

Tags: javascript, entity-framework, breeze, single-page-application

I am attempting to prime my Breeze cache with 3 data sets making a separate async WebApi request to each of the entity sets:

- Entity1: Person  (Principle)
- Entity2: Car
- Entity3: SpeedingTicket

The only two relationships are:

- Person has MANY Cars
- Person has MANY SpeedingTickets

I serve the MetaData to describe these relationships

The Question is:

Does Breeze need Person (principle) loaded into cache BEFORE the Cars and SpeedingTickets (dependents), to successfully make the associated foreign key relationships?
or can it handle the orphaned dependents loading first, and make the associations dynamically later when the Person (principle) is finally loaded?

**EDIT:** It seems that the order DOES matter

*EF Relationships:*

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().HasKey(p => p.Id);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
        .HasMany(p => p.Tickets)
        .WithRequired(t => t.Person)
        .HasForeignKey(t => t.PersonId);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()  
        .HasMany(p => p.Cars) 
        .WithRequired(c=>c.Person)
        .HasForeignKey(c=>c.PersonId);
```

*DataContext: Methods to retrieve People, Cars, Tickets (each remote and local)*

```
var DataContext = function() {
    function configureBreezeManager() {
        breeze.NamingConvention.camelCase.setAsDefault();
        return new breeze.EntityManager("http://localhost:7071/breeze/data/");;
    }

    var EntityQuery = breeze.EntityQuery,
        manager = configureBreezeManager();

    var
        QUERY_ALL_PERSONS = EntityQuery.from('People'),
        QUERY_ALL_CARS = EntityQuery.from('Cars'),
        QUERY_ALL_TICKETS = EntityQuery.from('Tickets');

    var
        querySuccess = function(result) {
            console.log("Fetched: " + result.query.resourceName);
        },
        queryFail = function(jqXhr, textStatus) {
            console.log("failed " + textStatus);
        };

    var
        getPersons = function() {
            return manager.executeQuery(QUERY_ALL_PERSONS)
                .then(querySuccess).fail(queryFail);
        },

        getCars = function() {
            return manager.executeQuery(QUERY_ALL_CARS)
                .then(querySuccess).fail(queryFail);
        },
        getTickets = function() {
            return manager.executeQuery(QUERY_ALL_TICKETS)
                .then(querySuccess).fail(queryFail);
        },

        //LOCALS

        getPersonsLocal = function() {
            return manager.executeQueryLocally(QUERY_ALL_PERSONS);
        },
        getCarsLocal = function() {
            return manager.executeQueryLocally(QUERY_ALL_CARS);
        },
        getTicketsLocal = function() {
            return manager.executeQueryLocally(QUERY_ALL_TICKETS);
        };

    return {
        getPersons: getPersons,
        getCars: getCars,
        getTickets: getTickets,

        getPersonsLocal: getPersonsLocal,
        getCarsLocal: getCarsLocal,
        getTicketsLocal: getTicketsLocal

    };          
};
```

Console output function:

```
function logLocalData() {
        var people = dc.getPersonsLocal(),
            cars = dc.getCarsLocal(),
            tickets = dc.getTicketsLocal();
        var pLen = people.length,
            cLen = cars.length,
            tLen = tickets.length;

        for (var p = 0 ; p < pLen; p++)
            console.log(people[p].name + " has " + people[p].cars.length + " car and " + people[p].tickets.length + " ticket");

        for (var t = 0 ; t < tLen; t++)
            console.log("ticket " + tickets[t].id + " belongs to person: " + (tickets[t].person));

        for (var c = 0 ; c < cLen; c++)
            console.log("car " + cars[c].id + " belongs to person: " + (cars[c].person));
}
```

**Below are 5 TESTS each loading the entities chained in different order, and the last test loading them in async**

**TEST1:** (OK) PEOPLE Loaded BEFORE dependents (breeze properly associates all 3 entities) - the desired result

```
var dc = new DataContext();
dc.getPersons()
    .then(dc.getCars)
    .then(dc.getTickets)
    .then(function () {
        logLocalData();
    })
```

```
    Fetched: People 
    Fetched: Cars 
    Fetched: Tickets 
    Joe has 1 car and 1 ticket 
    Sam has 1 car and 1 ticket 
    Bob has 1 car and 1 ticket 
    ticket 0 belongs to person: [object Object] 
    ticket 1 belongs to person: [object Object] 
    ticket 2 belongs to person: [object Object] 
    car 0 belongs to person: [object Object] 
    car 1 belongs to person: [object Object] 
    car 2 belongs to person: [object Object]
```

**TEST 2:** (FAIL) PEOPLE loaded AFTER dependents in order: CARS, TICKETS, PEOPLE (Notice TICKET>PERSON association is **null**, but CAR>PERSON is ok)

```
dc.getCars()
    .then(dc.getTickets)
    .then(dc.getPersons)
    .then(function () {
        logLocalData();
    })
```

```
Fetched: Cars
    Fetched: Tickets 
    Fetched: People
    Joe has 1 car and 0 ticket 
    Sam has 1 car and 0 ticket 
    Bob has 1 car and 0 ticket 
    ticket 0 belongs to person: null
    ticket 1 belongs to person: null
    ticket 2 belongs to person: null
    car 0 belongs to person: [object Object] 
    car 1 belongs to person: [object Object]
    car 2 belongs to person: [object Object]
```

**TEST 3:** (FAIL) PEOPLE loaded AFTER dependents in order: TICKETS, CARS, PEOPLE (Notice CAR>PERSON association is **null**, but TICKET>PERSON is ok) - the opposite of TEST 2*

```
dc.getTickets()
    .then(dc.getCars)
    .then(dc.getPersons)
    .then(function () {
        logLocalData();
    })
```

```
    Fetched: Tickets
    Fetched: Cars
    Fetched: People
    Joe has 0 car and 1 ticket
    Sam has 0 car and 1 ticket
    Bob has 0 car and 1 ticket
    ticket 0 belongs to person: [object Object] 
    ticket 1 belongs to person: [object Object] 
    ticket 2 belongs to person: [object Object]
    car 0 belongs to person: null 
    car 1 belongs to person: null 
    car 2 belongs to person: null
```

**TEST 4:** (OK) PEOPLE loaded 2ND in order: TICKETS,PEOPLE,CARS (breeze properly associates all 3 entities)

```
dc.getCars()
    .then(dc.getPersons)
    .then(dc.getTickets)
    .then(function () {
        logLocalData();
    })
```

```
Output is same as TEST 1
```

**TEST 5:** (FAIL) Using **Q.all** to load all sets asynchronously would have been my preferred approach, but it produces unpredictable results based on server response time for each call.

```
Q.all([ dc.getTickets(), dc.getCars(), dc.getPersons()])
    .then(function () {
        logLocalData();
    }).catch(function () { console.log("error"); })
```

```
    Output produces random results (could be any from TEST 1, 2, 3) based on server response time for each call.
```

**Conclusion**

- When loading the Principle BEFORE the 2 Dependents, all associations are properly made
- When loading the Principle IN BETWEEN the 2 Dependents, all associations are properly made
- When loading Principle AFTER the Dependents, the second
  Dependent is NOT associated and is left orphaned.

**Reiterating question**

Is this the expected behavior? Does Breeze need Person (principle) loaded into cache BEFORE the Cars and Tickets (dependents), to successfully make the associated foreign key relationships?  Or do I have a problem in the code?

This is a simplified example, I have many more entity sets loading into the SPA, and keeping track of loading order and staying synchronous is obviously not desired.

## Further Experimentation

I decided to take the attention away from Q.all/promises and query executions completely since that seemed to be taking focus away from the underlying problem. I also minimized the data to ONE object for each of the three entity types.

So here, I am left with the following:

- MetaData generated via EF6 context provider based on
  model-relationships described
- Manual creating of entities into breeze cache
- Person "Jim" should have one car and one ticket.

**TEST 6:** (OK) Notice order of calls -  Person created **FIRST**

```
mgr.metadataStore.fetchMetadata("http://localhost:7071/breeze/data/")
    .then(function() {

        mgr.createEntity('Person', { id: 1, name: 'Jim' });
        mgr.createEntity('Car', { id: 20, name: 'car', personId: 1 });
        mgr.createEntity('Ticket', { id: 30, personId: 1 });

    }).catch(function () { console.log("error"); })
   .done(function () {logLocalData();})
```

Everything Wired Well

```
    Jim(1) has 1 car and 1 ticket
    ticket 30 belongs to person: [object Object] 
    car 20 belongs to person: [object Object]
```

**TEST 7:** (FAIL)  Notice order of calls - Person created **LAST**, car object NOT wired to Person

```
mgr.metadataStore.fetchMetadata("http://localhost:7071/breeze/data/")
    .then(function() {

        mgr.createEntity('Ticket', { id: 30, personId: 1 });
        mgr.createEntity('Car', { id: 20, name: 'car', personId: 1 });
        mgr.createEntity('Person', { id: 1, name: 'Jim' });

    }).catch(function () { console.log("error"); })
   .done(function () {logLocalData();})
```

car object NOT wired to Person

```
    Jim(1) has 0 car and 1 ticket
    ticket 30 belongs to person: [object Object]
    car 20 belongs to person: null
```

**Where is the problem?**

- a) My Model relationships config?? (all the way at the top)
- b) My MetaData? (auto-generated by EFContextProvider) - i can paste it in formatted by request.
- c) Other

---

## Further, Further Experimentation: Isolating the Code even more.

- No more WebAPI
- No more EF-Generated Metadata
- No more server code
- No Q/promises
- Just Breeze, my client-side script, and me
- The Problem persists

I created the Metadata by hand, which is fairly simple using breeze's metadata-helper.

Ok, so here is my One script with reference to *breeze* & *breeze.metadata-helper*, nothing more, nothing less, problem remains:

```
    /********** METADATA GENERATOR **********/

    var MyMetaDataGenerator = function() {
        var keyGen = breeze.AutoGeneratedKeyType.Identity,
            namespace = 'genob.Model',
            helper = new breeze.config.MetadataHelper(namespace, keyGen);

        var DT = breeze.DataType, ID = DT.Int32;

        function createMetadataStore(serviceName) {
            var addType = function(type) { helper.addTypeToStore(store, type); };

            var store;

            store = new breeze.MetadataStore({
                namingConvention: breeze.NamingConvention.camelCase
            });
            helper.addDataService(store, serviceName);

            addPerson();
            addCar();
            addTicket();

            return store;

            function addPerson() {
                addType({
                    name: 'Person',
                    dataProperties: {
                        id: { type: ID },
                        name: { max: 50, nullOk: false }
                    },
                    navigationProperties: {
                        cars: { type: 'Car', hasMany: true },
                        tickets: { type: 'Ticket', hasMany: true }
                    }
                });
            }

            function addCar() {
                addType({
                    name: 'Car',
                    dataProperties: {
                        id: { type: ID },
                        name: { max: 50, nullOk: false },
                        personId: { type: ID, nullOk: false },
                    },
                    navigationProperties: {
                        person: 'Person',
                    }
                });
            }

            function addTicket() {
                addType({
                    name: 'Ticket',
                    dataProperties: {
                        id: { type: ID },
                        name: { max: 50, nullOk: false },
                        personId: { type: ID, nullOk: false },
                    },
                    navigationProperties: {
                        person: 'Person',
                    }
                });
            }

        }

        return {
            createMetadataStore: createMetadataStore
        };
    };

    /********** DATA CONTEXT **********/

    var DataContext = function () {

        var
            EntityQuery = breeze.EntityQuery,
            manager = configureBreezeManager();

        function configureBreezeManager() {
            var serviceName = "a/b",
                metaDataCreator = MyMetaDataGenerator(),
                store = metaDataCreator.createMetadataStore(serviceName),
                mgr = new breeze.EntityManager({
                    serviceName: serviceName,
                    metadataStore: store
                });
            return mgr;
        }

        var getManager = function() {
            return manager;
        };
        var
            getPersonsLocal = function() {
                return manager.executeQueryLocally(EntityQuery.from('Persons'));
            },
            getCarsLocal = function() {
                return manager.executeQueryLocally(EntityQuery.from('Cars'));
            },
            getTicketsLocal = function() {
                return manager.executeQueryLocally(EntityQuery.from('Tickets'));
            };

        return {
            getManager: getManager,

            getPersonsLocal: getPersonsLocal,
            getCarsLocal: getCarsLocal,
            getTicketsLocal: getTicketsLocal,
        };

    };

    ///////********** MY APP **********//////////

    var App = function() {
        var dc = new DataContext();

        function logLocalData() {
            var people = dc.getPersonsLocal(),
                cars = dc.getCarsLocal(),
                tickets = dc.getTicketsLocal();
            var pLen = people.length, cLen = cars.length, tLen = tickets.length;

            for (var p = 0; p < pLen; p++)
                console.log(people[p].name + "(" + people[p].id + ") has " + people[p].cars.length + " car and " + people[p].tickets.length + " ticket");

            for (var t = 0; t < tLen; t++)
                console.log("ticket " + tickets[t].id + " belongs to person: " + (tickets[t].person));

            for (var c = 0; c < cLen; c++)
                console.log("car " + cars[c].id + " belongs to person: " + (cars[c].person));
        }

        var run = function() {

            var mgr = dc.getManager();

            mgr.createEntity('Ticket', { id: 30, personId: 1 });
            mgr.createEntity('Car', { id: 20, personId: 1 });
            mgr.createEntity('Person', { id: 1, name: 'Jim' });

            logLocalData();
        };
        return {
            run: run
        };
    };

    App().run();
```

Output: Notice CAR>PERSON relationship is NOT wired, (note: if we first load CAR, then TICKET, well then the TICKET>PERSON is not wired, the second dependent never gets wired).

```
        Jim(1) has 0 car and 1 ticket 
        ticket 30 belongs to person: [object Object] 
        car 20 belongs to person: null
```

But, if we switch order to insert person FIRST:

```
    mgr.createEntity('Person', { id: 1, name: 'Jim' });
    mgr.createEntity('Ticket', { id: 30, personId: 1 });
    mgr.createEntity('Car', { id: 20, personId: 1 });
```

Output: All Relationships wired (all OK)

```
        Jim(1) has 1 car and 1 ticket 
        ticket 30 belongs to person: [object Object] 
        car 20 belongs to person: [object Object]
```

**Where is the problem?**

I have eliminated the impossible, and left only the improbable, so then what's the truth?

Comment: Have you tried it?  You can load them in any order, just make sure you don't try to bind to the properties before the entities are returned.

Comment: Yes have tried, I just updated the question with JS source. Omitting serve code unless requested.

Comment: Ok give me a minute and I will take a look.  As a note you need to return a promise from each of those calls if you are not already and catch them all with Q.all().  If you fail to return a promise it will continue on without a care.

Comment: That is indeed very true, catching when using Q is a must. In my case every breeze manager.executeQuery returns promise and is calling my querySuccess (and outputting "fetched...") so there shouldn't be  errors thrown here.

Comment: Can you show your full code around the Q.all() call?  For example what are you doing with the promise that Q.all returns?

Comment: I've added the logLocalData() , which I should have posted earlier.  All chains in my examples end with that (including Q.all). I am not really concerned with the Q.all, I am more concerned with TESTS 2 & 3, since I am taking control of the loading sequence in those and they are not NOT producing the desired results

Comment: Just to reiterate, in each of the 5 tests above, the logLocalData() is called AFTER all entities have been successfully loaded into the breeze cache. This is evident also by the fact that each "get...Local()" call retrieves and successfully enumerates all the objects from the cache. thanks.

Comment: The issue appears to be the order in which the two navigation properties *TYPES* are loaded, not directly the order in which the parent is loaded.  Check my answer / fiddle for a repro based off yours without using the metadata generator.

Comment: Check your fiddle, seems like a c/p oops. converting cars, and tickets to `.toType('Person'));`  after fix, still same output and opinion?

Comment: Actually it doesn't matter still same result - whichever method is called first is the only one of the two that is mapping inverse properties properly.  Put car anywhere after the first ticket and only the Tickets are mapped.  Put car first and only the car is mapped.

Comment: Anyway, it seems that as I mentioned originally, (At this point) "The order DOES matter" (sometimes).  I've been using the `[first-promise].then(Q.all(the-rest)` workaround for a few weeks now, but my application is rather more complex than my PERSON>CAR<TICKET example. So at this point, my workaround is becoming `first.then(second).then(Third,Forth,Fifth).then(Sixth).then(etc)` ..you can see why it's not a long term solution :)  .. A few days ago i finally decided to take my chances here with the code, in hopes of drawing attention in the unlikely case the issue was not in my code.

Comment: In most situations you would not load three related sets of entities in three separate queries as you are - you would use expand and never see this.  The bug is very specific in that it's not the order in which the parent is loaded but the order in which multiple children are loaded if they are loaded before a parent.  It's very specific but it is also repeatable.

Comment: 'BreezeJS is happy to accommodate you.' - Ward Bell

Answer (score 0):

### Edit

http://jsfiddle.net/G3mxq/4/

Looks like the issue is not that Person has to come last but that having two associations without inverse properties only cleans up the first one.  I have never used the metadataGenerator but the issue exists even without using it.

Check the fiddle for a repro and move the create car call near the very bottom to any other position in that list of create entity calls.

Until it can be addressed you can just call getPeople().executeQuery() first and on the returned promise go get the other two.

### Original

I think that your problem here is that you are not using `Q.all()` correctly, but it's hard to tell without seeing what is calling it and how it is working.

```
function getData() {
    var promise = Q.all([ dc.getTickets(), dc.getCars(), dc.getPersons()]);

    return promise.then(querySuccess);

    function querySuccess() {
        // Check that everything has been returned
    }
}
```

As long as all three of your calls are returning a promise it should wait until all of the calls are finished before proceeding.

Comment: The problem is not that the promise is not waiting...it is waiting, as illustrated in the output. The problem is the order in which each call is executed and bound to breeze seems to vary the output.  But as I mentioned, my question is specifically not regarding Q.all, my other 4 tests examples are executed in sequence, where TEST 2 & 3 are not resulting in proper entity associations.

Comment: In your model do you have a two way association or is the association only one way?  If you have car > tickets and ticket > car then Breeze will create the inverse relationships for you.  Internally Breeze relies on Q. to ensure the data comes back at the right time, but of course your model associations have to be correct.

Comment: Added EF Relationships to code. I have two-way on each TICKET>PERSON  and CAR>PERSON.  No relation between TICKET-CAR. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Breeze should not care about the order in which entities arrive. If you wait until they all arrive, they should all be wired up. Something is amiss for sure.

Your code was looking good until I stumbled into the reporter function, `logLocalData`.

You're using the JavaScript `for` that iterates over the properties of an OBJECT.

```
for (var p in people)
    console.log(people[p].name + " has " + people[p].cars.length + 
                " car and " + people[p].tickets.length + " ticket");
```

That kind of works in your case (else you wouldn't have seen anything). And this error does not explain your results. But it is incorrect. You want the `for` that iterates over the ELEMENTS OF AN ARRAY.

```
for (var p, len=people.length; p < len; p++)
    console.log(people[p].name + " has " + people[p].cars.length + 
                " car and " + people[p].tickets.length + " ticket");
```

Or the `forEach` method of an ES5 array

```
people.forEach(function(p) {
    console.log(p.name + " has " + p.cars.length + 
                " car and " + p.tickets.length + " ticket");
});
```

Please try that, add a `catch` to the `Q.all`, and then tell us what you see.

### A DocCode Test of 3 related queries

Because this is a common scenario, I added a passing [demonstration test to the DocCode sample](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js.samples/blob/master/net/DocCode/DocCode/tests/queryTests.js). It uses Knockout but that shouldn't matter. Maybe you'll find something illuminating in it.

```
/*********************************************************
* When run separate queries for Employee, Orders, EmployeeTerritories.
* Breeze will wire up their relationships.
* 
* These next tests are a response to the SO question
* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24001496/breeze-js-priming-loading-and-caching-data-via-asynchronous-requests
*
* The tests verify the entity wiring after all queries have finished.
*
* Note that Employee has many Orders and many EmployeeTerritories
* which matches the SO question's model structure
*********************************************************/
asyncTest("Can run parallel queries and breeze will wire relationships", 5, function () {
    var em = newEm();
    var queries = make_Emp_Orders_EmpTerritories_Query(em);
    var all = [
        queries.eQuery.execute(),
        queries.etQuery.execute(),
        queries.oQuery.execute()
    ];
    Q.all(all)
    .then(function () { check_Emp_Orders_EmpTerritories(queries); })
    .catch(handleFail).finally(start);
});

asyncTest("Can chain queries, dependent first, and breeze will wire relationships", 5, function () {
    var em = newEm();
    var queries = make_Emp_Orders_EmpTerritories_Query(em);
    // Run dependent entity queries first starting with Orders
    queries.oQuery.execute()
    // then EmployeeTerritories
    .then(function () { return queries.etQuery.execute(); })
    // lastly the principal (Employee) query
    .then(function () { return queries.eQuery.execute(); })
    // now assert that everything is wired up
    .then(function () { check_Emp_Orders_EmpTerritories(queries); })
    .catch(handleFail).finally(start);
});

function make_Emp_Orders_EmpTerritories_Query(em) {
    var eQuery = EntityQuery.from("Employees").using(em)
            .where('EmployeeID', '==', 1); // trim to just Nancy
    var etQuery = EntityQuery.from("EmployeeTerritories").using(em);
    var oQuery = EntityQuery.from("Orders").using(em)
             .where('EmployeeID', '==', 1); // trim to just Nancy's orders 
    return {
        eQuery: eQuery,
        etQuery: etQuery,
        oQuery: oQuery
    };
}

function check_Emp_Orders_EmpTerritories(queries) {
    var emps           = queries.eQuery.executeLocally();
    var empTerritories = queries.etQuery.executeLocally();
    var orders         = queries.oQuery.executeLocally();

    equal(emps.length, 1, "should have one Employee (Nancy)");
    notEqual(orders.length, 0, "should have Orders");
    notEqual(empTerritories.length, 0, "should have EmployeeTerritories");

    var e1 = emps[0];
    var e1Name = e1.FirstName();
    var e1OrdersLen = e1.Orders().length;
    var e1EmpTerritoriesLen = e1.EmployeeTerritories().length;

    notEqual(e1OrdersLen, 0,
        "'{0}' has {1} Orders".format(e1Name, e1OrdersLen));
    notEqual(e1EmpTerritoriesLen, 0,
        "'{0}' has {1} EmployeeTerritories".format(e1Name, e1EmpTerritoriesLen));
};
```

Notice that the asserts exercise the navigation properties and pull values from cache.

Feel free to juggle the order of the chained promises. It shouldn't matter.

Comment: Oh-great-one, you responded to my prayers :) I got cute with the "for".. that was an silly oops. Fixed that iteration part, but results of tests are still same.

Comment: Updated with a DocCode test

Comment: Ward, after taking a walk and coming back to the desk .. I did find something illuminating - your inspiration to keep whacking away at it.  Please see my update "Further Experimentation" - no Q (almost), no server requests aside from metadata fetch.

Comment: LOL. I just updated my test (made two of them) to more closely match your structure while still using Northwind. I wonder what remains to be explained. I don't think the promises are the issue either. I need to move on for a while. Something upstream I guess. Try downloading the DocCode sample when you get a chance and try to find the difference.

Comment: I'll come back later if you haven't figured it out. Something fishy about `Car` metadata. What does the `mgr.metadataStore.getEntityType('Person')` say about the navigations between Person and Ticket and Car

Comment: Not `Car` specifically, as when I flip entity insertion order of `Car` and `Ticket` it's the `Ticket` that gets orphaned. Anyway, I'll look into NWdb/DocCode, nav props, maybe will also write the metadata from scratch, then we'll see. thanks

Comment: Ward, had the pleasure to look through the DocCode, all i can say that it's rock-solid. I juggled promises in the tests, messed around with the EF relationship declaration between Employees, Emp-Terr & Orders,  added/removed InverseProperties, tried attributes vs fluentAPI - no-give: couldn't get your code to break, couldn't get mine to work. :) However, I managed to even further isolate the issue, creating my own metadata, getting rid of server requests completely - please see my update.  btw- i don't think your Controller & Context queries for EmployeeTerritories made it into the repo.

Comment: Didn't understand: "i don't think your Controller & Context queries for EmployeeTerritories made it into the repo."Please, would you elaborate so I can fix?

Comment: The 2 new DocCode tests were failing until I added IQueryable<EmployeeTerritory> EmployeeTerritories() method into NorthwindController and subsequently into NorthwindRepository, to query that table directly.

Comment: Ah ... right. But then I changed the example to Orders, Employees, Customers and I didn't need `EmployeeTerritory` anymore. So I didn't commit it. Try pulling the repo again. Sorry for the hassle.

Comment: Oops.. Had that BACKWARDS. Changed TO Orders, Employees, *EmployeeTerritories* and neglected to check in the server side code ... just as you said. Fixed it now.